# Problem with using @@DBTS between the primary and secondary in an AG

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, etl

I have an ETL process that uses rowversion field and had an issue, because the ETL process was using the source database which had become out of sync in an AG, so I read the rowversion data from the secondary node, and I have had unknown problems since the change was put into place.  I can query @@DBTS on the source database (primary node) and see it moving right along, but when querying on the readable secondary node, I see two odd things.  One the value is not moving at all, though I know it has moved looking at logs.  Two it is a larger value than on the primary.  I am starting to think that the value is not stored in the actual database, and if it is why would it not be synced with the primary? I tried changing the AG to synchronous just to see if anything happened and it didn't.  Does anyone have any insight to this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not familiar with `@@DBTS` but its description makes it sound a little suspect for what you're trying to do. What does the [Availability Group Dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/use-the-always-on-dashboard-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16) say in regards to the replicas being synchronized?...particularly the `Synchronization State`, `Estimated Recovery Time (seconds)`, and `Redo Queue Size (KB)` columns?